# No exception thrown from Base32 after commons-codec upgrade

Tags: java, totp, apache-commons-codec

I have a [TOTP Authenticator](https://totp-authenticator.eu-gb.mybluemix.net) project which generates a six-digit one-time password using [TOTP (RFC 6238)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238). Internally it uses [Base32](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base32.html) class from Apache Commons Codec:

```java
Base32 base32 = new Base32();
```

Following the [commons-codec](https://search.maven.org/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec) upgrade **1.14 -> 1.15**, a unit test started to fail:

```java
@Test
void testInvalidBase32Value() {
  String secretKey = "AHXQ2W5P6AGKYVK";

  Executable when = () -> generator.generateOtp(secretKey);

  assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, when);
}
```

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.lang.IllegalArgumentException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

How do I fix the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Apache Commons Codec [1.15 release notes](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/changes-report.html#a1.15), the default decoding policy has been changed:

> Base32/Base64/BCodec: Added strict decoding property to control handling of trailing bits. Default lenient mode discards them without error. Strict mode raise an exception.

The new default decoding policy is defined in [BaseNCodec.java](https://github.com/apache/commons-codec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BaseNCodec.java#L187):

```java
protected static final CodecPolicy DECODING_POLICY_DEFAULT = CodecPolicy.LENIENT;
```

To fix the unit test, set the decoding policy to [CodecPolicy.STRICT](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/CodecPolicy.html#STRICT) in `generateOtp()`:

```java
Base32 base32 = new Base32();
->
Base32 base32 = new Base32(0, null, false, PAD_DEFAULT, CodecPolicy.STRICT);
```

Now data that causes a codec to fail should throw an exception.